# PHP - preg multiple result

Tags: php, preg-match

i have code like this:

```
<?
$source = '!Hello, this is !PHP!HTML !@language';
preg_match("'!(.*?)'si", $source, $match);
if($match) print_r($match);
?>
```

and i want to get result like:

```
!Hello
!PHP
!HTML
!@language
```

anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead of `preg_match`

```
preg_match_all("/![@a-z]*/si", $source, $match);
```

`preg_match` returns only first match.

Answer (score 4):

Change to:

```
preg_match_all("/![a-z@]*/i", $source, $match);
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/dIHIe).

Answer (score 0):

```
$source = '!Hello, this is !PHP!HTML !@language';
preg_match_all("~![^(!|\s|,)]*~si", $source, $match);
if($match) print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $haystack = "!Hello, this is !PHP!HTML !@language";
    $needle = "/!([^\s\!,])*/";

    $matches;
    preg_match_all($needle,$haystack,$matches);

    foreach($matches[0] as $match)
    {
        echo $match . "\n";
    }   
?>
```